# Recursive query rows to single column?

Tags: sql, recursion, db2, ibm-midrange

1) What are recursive queries ?
2) Are they dangerous ?
3) How can I make a recursive query to give me results from

```
ID Date
1  10/10/2010
1  20/10/2010
1  20/10/2010
2  11/10/2010
2  22/10/2010
```

to

```
   ID  Dates
    1  10/10/2010,20/10/2010,20/10/2010
    2  11/10/2010,22/10/2010
```

4) Can you explain how recursion operates inside the query? I googled but can't get how the recursion works actually. My database is DB2 ISeries V5R4.

Comment: You're asking for pivoting, not recursion

Comment: yeah, I actually don't understand his question. There is no requirement and there are lots of ways to come up with his result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive query is a SQL query that can do a recursive computation. In other words, it can use the results of itself to continue query. Here is an abstract description:

```
1/ ancestor (x, y) = parent (x, y)

2/ ancestor (x, y) = parent (x, z) && ancestor (Z, Y).
```

It can be understood in a brief way that you to list all ancestor of Z, you list all of its parents and then all parents of those parents...

For example, if you have a table of Family with 2 columns Parent and Child like this:

```
pkey  char  1  not null  primary key
ckey  char  1  not null  primary key

('A','B') 
('A','C') 
('A','D')  
('C','E')  
('D','A')  
('D','E')  
('D','F')  
('F','G')
```

The left handside is parent and the right hand side is children. Now you want to find all descedants of A then here is some code:

```
with parent_ctl (ckey) as 
(
select ckey
    from parents
        where pkey='A'
UNION ALL
select c.ckey
    from parents C, parent_ctl P
        where P.ckey = C.Pkey
)
select ckey from parent_ctl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply fellow. What if I wanted to list all 2nd column values for the record with ID 'A' in a single column like 'A' - 'B,C,D' ?

Comment: What is the order of query that gets executed ? First the parent query, then all results from UNION all, is that the correct order ?

Comment: I will try to give you a summary, but it is kinda a lot about this. I don't really get the first question. My query should do the job well, isn't it? The order is that you run the top query first to select all the direct children. DB save the data in some place called D, then it uses D to generate the next direct childrent of D called E, then D and E is unioned. Continue the process until either the query below UNION ALL returns empty set

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, please check my original post's example. How can I list my rows with comma separated values ?

Comment: Query is MSSQL specific and would definitely NOT work on DB2.

Comment: @Pavel Urbančík: Why not, (even recursive) CTE's are supported in DB2 aren't they? or is it something else?